# Is it possible to build this app for Quickbooks?

Tags: user-interface

I use intuit merchant services - customers pay me with credit card after I send them an email with a link to pay, and everything works with no problem.  However, my problem is that the link webpage structure is very outdated and some customers have told me that it doesn't look trustworthy, which I have to agree.

Is there any solution to this, like creating a user interface or a app that I can actually have developed to make this links a little bit more to look like my website so customers don't feel they ever left my website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You should be careful with this idea**.  I am not a legal professional and am in no way attempting to give legal advice, but doing what you are suggesting **can be illegal** in some cases.  Some sites disguise their payment screens in a similar way for malicious purposes in a manner called [phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing), and there may be **little legal differentiation between doing so with good or ill intent**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible but here is what you actually can do:

- Ask your Payment-Website about an API, then you might be able to change the layout.
- Inform your customers about the situation and that they will be redirected of whatever you do.
- Get a SSL-Cert for your website.
- Find another way to receive payments in a trustworthy way

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check with intuit.